# Why are older people more likely to be a victim of romance scammers than young people?

Tags: scams, fraud

I have this curiosity. Statistics show that most people who are victims of romance scams are middle aged or elderly people(and female) but younger people rarely fall for this kind of fraud. Young people are more tech savy so they are used to use tools to verify if a person is legit and telling the truth like for example use the reverse image search tool. But there are other factors that make a young person an unnatractive target for romance scammers.

Young people rarely have a lot of money and assets that can be scammed out like a high savings, high income and assets that can be sold by a high price like a house. Of course there are young rich people but they are pretty rare.

In my opinon when young people get into a relationship even if it is online they expect something sexual from it since they have usually higher sex drive than older people on average. So the young will want to exchange nudes, sexting, webcam videos, bikini and langerie photos among other things that indicate a sexual bound. Talking of nudes it becomes hard for the scammer to get enough nudes from the person they are pretending to be unless if they are catfishing as a model or a pornstar which are often famous and have a lot of links in any search engine. Moreover young people are more tech savy as I said earlier and will want to make a video chat to verify if the person they are interacting is real and not catfishing. It is easy to fake photos but it is much harder to fake a video call albeit it is possible. If someone continously refuse to attend a video call then this person is hiding something. Older people will usually overlook this redflag and they are usually wealthier and far less familiar with technology making them a more attractive target for the fraudsters. Moreover older people on average have lower sex drive which means that sex and intimacy is not so important for them as it is for a young person. Trust, companionship and friendship are more important for older people in a relationship.

And technically if a young couple online is sending money to each other but they are receiving something sexual like nudes and cleavage photos and something then it is sugaring not scamming as I read on Reddit.

Sorry if I answered my own question but I want other people`s opinions.

Comment: Opinion-based answers/questions are off-topic here. But it sounds like you answered your own question anyway. Older people, on average: 1) have more money 2) are less tech-savvy 3) are more trusting of strangers on the internet

Comment: I'll also point out that this site frequently gets scam questions from individuals being blackmailed by supposed 'sugar daddies' [which I would consider the other side of the typical 'romance scam' coin]. There are a lot of different scams out there; most of them come down to "ain't nothing in this world for free".

Comment: Like Willie Sutton said in response to "Why do you rob banks?": "Because that's where the money is"

Comment: Perhaps better suited for the Psychology site (I think there is one), or perhaps Interpersonal Relations?  My two cents worth?  When you're young, you can fairly easily meet potential romantic partners in bars & clubs, college classes, and so on.  As you get older, those opportunities tend to fade away.  There's also less selection, since so many have already paired up and become unavailable.

Comment: [citation needed] for the claim that older people get romance-scammed more often than younger people. Just look at all the college-aged girls who ask [Am I being scammed by my sugar daddy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy).

Comment: @shoover: I think the sugar daddy (or mommy) scams fall into a somewhat different category.  The would-be sugar babies (of the on-line variety) aren't looking for romance.  They're basically would-be scammers themselves, expecting their sugar parents to give them money for little more than on-line conversation and perhaps some explicit pictures.

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty much spot on with most of your analysis, if I had to answer the question without you providing your own answers, I would cite the following:

- Newsworthiness.  Older people tend to have more assets, so it makes for a better news story.  Also they tend not to have an opportunity to recoup their losses.
- Sophistication.  Older people tend not to be as tech savvy as those that are younger and are less likely to know about things like photoshopping and the ability to hide one's identity.
- Living out regrets.  With advanced age and death approaching, perhaps they want to break out of limits that were placed upon them by society or themselves.
- Embarrassment/Inability to research.  They are less likely to tell their friends, or ask others opinions.

Most people that contact this site about "Sugar daddy/momma" contacts tend to be younger people.  Most people want to believe they can get something for nothing so technically all are potential victims.  However reaching out to a friend or anonymously to an online community can give one perspective and prevent the actual fraud from happening.

The "scam" plaguing most young people today, to me, is buying significant assets jointly with a gf/bf and no legal agreement.

Comment: Is it also possible that with aging people actually become less wise in the sense that they begin to lose their ability to distinguish what is legit and what is fake despite having more life experiences?